# Prepare JSON in Python app for consumption by React

Tags: python, json, reactjs

**Question**

My Python app needs to generate a JSON file that will be consumed by React.  The Python app generates lists similar to the following:

```
animals = ["dog","cat","fish"]
count = [3,6,1]
```

**What have I tried**

I can dump this to JSON using `zip` and a `dict`:

```
json.dumps(dict(zip(animals,count)))

'{"dog": 3, "cat": 6, "fish": 1}'
```

**Desired output**

I would like the JSON to look like this:

```
'[{"name":"dog","count":3},{"name":"cat","count":6},{"name":"fish","count":1}]'
```

What is the most Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: I am not sure there is a "pythonic" way of doing this, but more of just a programmatic way. What you need is to iterate through those 2 arrays (or at least one of them), and create your animal objects to be appended to your final array. [Iterate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919448/iterating-over-arrays-in-python-3) | [Create list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348196/creating-a-list-of-objects-in-python/348215). I am not a python guru, so others may have actual pythonic abilities beyond me :)

Comment: Do you want your json to be a single object of only the first animal and count or do you want a json array containing 3 objects each containing an animal name and count?

Comment: @steviestickman please see updated desired output

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your question has two parts: How to represent an animal population in json
and how to represent a group of animal populations in json.
the json module can convert some python data structures to json data structures.

you can represent an animal population as a dict containing a name and a count.

then you need to construct a list that contains an animal population for each type of animal.

```py
animal_names = ["dog", "cat", "fish"]
animal_counts = [3, 6, 1]


def animal_population(name, count):
    """
    >>> animal_population('dog', 3)
    {'name': 'dog', 'count': 3}
    """
    return {
        'name': name,
        'count': count
    }


animals = [
    animal_population(name, count)
    for name, count in zip(animal_names, animal_counts)
]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json
    print(json.dumps(animals))
```

output:

```
[{"name": "dog", "count": 3}, {"name": "cat", "count": 6}, {"name": "fish", "count": 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually came up with this which appears to be the simplest approach:

```
json.dumps([{'name': name, 'count': count} for name,count in zip(animals,count)])
```

**Output:**

```
'[{"name": "dog", "count": 3}, {"name": "cat", "count": 6}, {"name": "fish", "count": 1}]'
```