# List element (object) not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, object, pytest, list-comprehension

I want to create a unit test for a function which sorts a list of objects according to some object attribute(s). Here is a code sample:

```
class Foo:
    """Custom data type Foo."""

    def __init__(self,
                 a: str,
                 b: int,
                 c: int,
                 d: int,
                 e: int,
                 f: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
        self.g = c * d * e
        self.h = c * d
```

This is a part of the unit test function which produces the error:

```
from random import randint
...
class Test(TestCase):

def test_item_sort_foo(self):
    random_list = [Foo(str(randint(0, 1000)),
                        randint(0, 100),
                        randint(0, 100),
                        randint(0, 100),
                        randint(0, 100),
                        randint(0, 100))
                   for x in range(100)]
...
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: 'Foo' object is not subscriptable.
```

Despite reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not), I cannot understand why Python cares if `Foo` is subscriptable since `random_list` already is. I'm trying to generate a list of random `Foo` items similarly to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348196/creating-a-list-of-objects-in-python). I am puzzled because I already have a (working) class of the kind

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Bar:
    """Bar custom data type."""
    i: str
    j: List[Foo]
```

And I can type, e.g.,

```
f = Foo(...)
b = Bar("baz", [])
b.j.append(f)
```

So here are my questions:

- Do elements of subscriptable objects also have to be subscriptable? Why?
- What is the best way to generate random data with the properties from above for testing?
- How do I apply this principle for my case?

EDIT: This is the complete unit testing function:

```
def test_item_sort_foo(self):
        random_list = [Foo(str(randint(0, 1000)),
                            randint(0, 100),
                            randint(0, 100),
                            randint(0, 100),
                            randint(0, 100),
                            randint(0, 100))
                       for x in range(100)]
        sorted_list = item_sort_foos(random_list)
        assert eq(sorted_list, sorted(random_list,
                                      key=itemgetter(4, 7),
                                      reverse=True))
```

And here is the code of the function which implements the logic:

```
def item_sort_foos(foos: List[Foo]) -> List[Foo]
    return sorted(foos,
                  key=attrgetter("e", "h"),
                  reverse=True)
```

EDIT2: The full trace is:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py", line 628, in run
    testMethod()
  File ".../src/project/tests/test_orderings.py", line 89, in test_item_sort_foos
    reverse=True))
TypeError: 'Foo' object is not subscriptable
```

If you need any additional info, please request in the comments.

Comment: This question has insufficient code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which additional information should I provide?

Comment: Everything that I need in order to get the same TypeError.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? After removing a few bits of cruft the code produced the random_list okay. I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Try and simplify by having only 1 str and 1 int argument.

Comment: Timgeb is right: you should post exactly the code and the command that produces the error.

Something that another person can run verbatim and get the error.

Comment: `key=itemgetter(4, 7)` - is trying `__getitem__` on Foo objects (e.g., `foo[4], foo[7]`). I'm not sure what you want sort order to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random_list` is a list of `Foo` objects. When you use a sort key of `key=itemgetter(4, 7)`, you are trying to index the foo object itself. Its the same as

```
foo = Foo(...)
sort_key = foo[4], foo[7]
```

Likely you want to use `key=attrgetter("e", "h")` as in the `item_sort_foos` function you are testing.

But this is test code. `item_sort_foos` is a very small function and if all you do is put its guts in your unit test, you haven't tested much. Instead you should pass in some canned lists that you already know what the output is supposed to be. Compare those.

Comment: Indeed, itemgetter was used wrongly. Probably a parentheses issue; will edit my q

Comment: I don't get the "canned" part though - is a list with random elements not best practice?

Comment: This is a unit test which is "given input A expect output B". If you are putting in random numbers then you don't really know what to expect unless you just implement the same algorithm a second time. You want multiple tests. What happens with zero items? 1 item? 5 items with known sorting? Several items that compare the same? These will all produce previously determined output. How does 100 items really test anything, especially when there isn't a predetermined output.